# MySql multiple statements in query in Google Apps

Tags: mysql, google-apps-script, jdbc

I'm using Google Apps Script to connect to my MySql database and run a query. I'm using a "standard" `var conn = Jdbc.getCloudSqlConnection (dbUrl, user, userPwd)` and `stmt.executeQuery(QUERY)`. This all works great. I now have a need to run multiple queries, like `SET @DateFrom='2020-12-01'; SET @DateTo='2020-12-31'; SELECT * FROM database WHERE MyDate BETWEEN @DateFrom AND @DatoTo`. But this fails in GAS and I haven't found a way to run multiple queries. Is it even possible? Thanks!

Comment: You can create a stored procedure on your MySQL server with a sequence of multiple statements and then invoke the stored procedure using a CALL statement from Google Apps Script.

Comment: Thanks @TheAddonDepot but I really want to be able to write the queries in Google Sheet (we use this extensively).

Answer (score 0):

Figured out how to do it with a little trial and error.
You need to execute multiple `stmt.executeQuery(QUERY)` – one for each query (obviously).

I first created a function to clean and split up the string into an array:

```
 function oTrimAndSplit(inputString, delimiter) {
  var trimmed = inputString.trim();
  var length = trimmed.length;
  if (trimmed.slice(-1) == ";") trimmed = trimmed.slice(0, -1);
  var arr = trimmed.split(delimiter);
  return arr;
}
```

Then wrap it all up:

```
var conn = Jdbc.getCloudSqlConnection (dbUrl, user, userPwd);
var queries = oTrimAndSplit(QUERY, ';');
queries.forEach(function(queriesElement) {
   stmt.executeQuery(queriesElement)
});
```

And that's it!